# Connecting a NetBeans Platform Application to diffrent DBMS using the same schema with jpa

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans-platform

I need to make an application where the user can configure some connection parameters like server and DBMS (specifically MySQL, MSSQL and Oracle). As long as the database schema is the same, but not the server in order to use the servers already working in the client's intranet, I'm trying to find a way to force jpa use the parameters set by the user and make the transaction.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use the property file contains information about the DB, username and password which will change according to the d